# jquery Datatable Search shows removed data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using datatable of http://datatables.net/

My Scenario is I change the content of table based on some event.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="dataTable0">
   <thead>
      <tr style="width: 100%;">                         
         <th>Campaign Name</th>
         <th>Schedule</th>
         <th>List</th>  
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody id="CampaignTableViewBody"></tbody>
</table>
```

INITIALIZED SCRIPT FOR DATATABLE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   oTable = $('#dataTable0').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bScrollCollapse": false,
    "sScrollY": "200px",
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers", //full_numbers,two_button
    "bStateSave": false,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]]
  });
});
```

FILLING DATA DYNAMICALLY

```
$("#CampaignTableViewBody").empty();
$("#CampaignTableViewBody").append(
     '<tr>'+ 
        '<td>'+obj.name+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+obj.startTime+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+obj.listTemplateUsed+'</td>'+                            
      '</tr>');
```

I have one dropdown say Select ClassRoom : 
I am filling all Students data in Table belonging to Selected Classroom dynamically.

Say classroom "A" is Selected, then I will show "Rahul","Jason" in table

Now If user change class room then I am removing all data from table by using `$("#CampaignTableViewBody").empty();` and iterating fresh data in the table.

Say classroom "B" is selected then I remove all data in table, then I will show "Mayur","John" in table.

But problem here is when I search in the search box in the datatable provided with Word "Rahul", then it shows the rows which should not be case because class "B" is Selected and class B doesn't has Rahul.

while filling data in table all goes good, I can see only 2 rows ie of  "Mayur" and "John", Only problem is in data table searching, which gives older data in result which no longer exist.

Any idea how to overcome it.

Comment: you aren't realizing that the plugin doesn't just manipulate html. It stores html as well as data in cached arrays. You need to use the plugin API to add and remove data

Comment: @charlietfl : You are right. I am idiot that I didn't read api properly and coded much code in above fashion. can you tell me workaround on this.

Comment: what do you mean a workaround? Why can't you use the API?

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'Destroy' the previous DataTable

```
$("#dataTable0").dataTable().fnDestroy(); // Destroy the previous table
$("#CampaignTableViewBody").empty(); // Empty (remove any DOM elements)


$("#CampaignTableViewBody").append( 
     '<tr>'+ 
        '<td>'+obj.name+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+obj.startTime+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+obj.listTemplateUsed+'</td>'+                            
      '</tr>'); // Append the new information 

$("#dataTable0").dataTable(settings); // Recreate the datatable
```

Hope this works for you!
More Api functions here: http://datatables.net/api

Good luck with the implementation.